# Django FileField() disable upload

Tags: django

I have a `FileField()` in a Django model. On `save()`, I intercept this and upload the actual file data to a remote-backend/Bucket, then save the URL returned from the service in another field.

The file actually uploads to my file-system (I believe).

**How can I disable the `FileField()` to not actually upload the file to wherever media is stored with Django?**

Comment: did you override the `save()` method? Pls add that too

Comment: I ran into something similar. I have a management command that saves files from the result of an api and save these files to directory. I am trying to save these files to a django model and set its File \Field with the reference from a already downloaded file. When, I try to `save` the model, it creates a duplicate file. I want to skip the `upload_to` in `FileField`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `upload_to` atttribute of FileField.

Reference: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to